# ASP .net MVC form contenteditable null on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable form I'm trying to POST from a form which will be handled by an Action method but I get null for its POST data.

I first define my form:

```
<form class="composer-form" name="input" action="~/Articles/ResearchArticles/ArticleSubmit" method="post" onsubmit="return SubmitForm()">
                    @RenderPage("text-editor-partial.cshtml")
                    <textarea id="hidden_text_area" style="display: none"></textarea>
                    <div style="padding-left: 2em">
                        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" style="width: 200px">
                    </div>
```

As the above code shows, the SubmitForm function will handle the copying of the value of the content editable which looks like this:

```
function SubmitForm() {
    var clr = confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the article?");
    if (clr == true) {
        var hta = document.getElementById("hidden_text_area");
        var content_html = document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML;
        hta.value = content_html;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code successfully gets the value from the contenteditable div and puts it in the hidden text value field.
So now I have an action that I get from this like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ArticleSubmit(string postData)
{
  return new EmptyResult(); //postData is NULL... why?
}
```

Setting a breakpoint shows postData as null... What is my stupid mistake :) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textarea needs a `name`, otherwise the model binder won't fetch its value when you submit your form :

```
<textarea id="hidden_text_area" style="display: none" name="postData"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to use a hidden `input` instead of `textarea`, since it does not have a `value`, actually the contents are stored in a `text`.

So in HTML:

```
<input id="hidden_input" style="display: none" name="data" />
```

And in Controller:

```
public ActionResult ArticleSubmit(string data)
{

}
```